# Horizontal alignment of elements in css

Tags: html, css

I am quite of a newbie in css and don't manage to figure out how to solve this little issue. I have the following footer in my html:

[image]

and in code:

```
 <footer>
        <a href="#" class="btn-reset-search-form" data-bind="click: ..." data-i18n="..."></a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-submit-search" data-bind="click: ..." data-i18n="..."></button>
 </footer>
```

As you can see in the next picture, with the red line, there is an horizontal alignment (I guess):

[image]

But what I want to achieve is that they get aligned like this:

[image]

In other words, the Reset link should be at the same level of the Submit button. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use display:inline-block in both div and in reset link you need provide same height as submit button div. And both div will be vertical-align:middle; Or Add css of this code

Comment: @kittyCat there is no css.. those are just id's to identify the elements through the class

Comment: @Tarta there must be css to show how you have it currently - ie what is positioning your button on the right and the reset on the left?

Answer (score 0):

Set some margin-top to the Reset

```
a
{
   margin-top:5px //as your need

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align:bottom;` alongwith `display:inline-block;`

See the below snippet.

```css
footer{
  border:1px solid black;
  
}
button{
  height:40px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <a href="">Reset</a>
  <button>Submit</button>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
footer{
  border:1px solid black;
  
}
a{height:40px;vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block;line-height:40px;}
    button{
      height:40px;
      vertical-align:bottom;
      display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

```html
<footer>
  <a href="">Reset</a>
  <button>Submit</button>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
footer{
  border:1px solid black;
  
}
a{
  height:40px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:40px;
}
    button{
      height:40px;
      vertical-align:bottom;
      display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;
      float:right;
    }
```

```html
<footer>
  <a href="">Reset</a>
  <button>Submit</button>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap framework, try using a grid system by adding a right align for the second column. Then add a line-height to a link equal to the height of the button to have a horizontal alignment centered

See the following code

HTML

```
<footer>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <a href="#" class="btn-reset-search-form" data-bind="click: ..." data-i18n="...">Reset</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-submit-search" data-bind="click: ..." data-i18n="...">submit</button>
  </div>
</div>  
 </footer>
```

CSS

```
footer{ display:block; border-top:1px solid #DDD; margin:20px; padding:8px 0;}

.btn-reset-search-form{
    display:inline-block; line-height:40px;
}

.btn-submit-search{
    height:40px;
}
```